# UISplitViewController - open in portrait mode with masterViewController visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` which keeps the master and detail views visible in both portrait and landscape orientations. Everything works fine except that when the page opens in portrait mode, the `masterViewController` is hidden until I rotate the screen and rotate it back. Any idea how I can force the `masterViewController` to stay visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the relevant delegate methods of the split view, and return values which prevent the closing of the master view.